# AudioTrack performance

Tags: android, performance, audio

I'm using `AudioTrack` in Stream mode for output audio data (several audio files mixed programmatically) and from trace I see that `write` method has different execution time. Usually it is ~50 msec but sometimes it is only 0.03 (rare situations).

Here is trace from Nexus 7:
[image: Trace]
Green is for mixer logic and red is for `write` calls.

I have two questions:

1. If I move to OpenSL will I get better performance?
2. Why sometimes `write` method has so low execution time and could it be predictable?

Comment: Which mode are you using? `static` or `streaming`?

Comment: @SamRad sorry, forgot about this detail. Added to question.

Comment: This is normal behavior for a blocking API: The write call blocks until the data is needed. I don't know if there is a way to predict how long the call will take in Android. This may help: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2011/11/slides-from-fundamentals-of-audio.html

Comment: @BjornRoche ok, and if I move to async with OpenSL will it solve problem?

Comment: I don't know OpenSL, but callbacks won't necessarily be called at an exactly regular rate with most API's either. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @BjornRoche I'm trying to understand is it a problem or not. I don't know what execution time for `write` method I could consider "good" or suitable. Could you tell me will I have a smooth play with such execution time?

Comment: It is the job of the audio API you are using to provide the hardware with audio when it needs it, and it is the job of the hardware to play the audio back smoothly. As long as the audio api can do its job, audio will play back smoothly.